# Btree implementation

Tags: java, data-structures, b-tree

I'm writing the model of database which is using the B+ tree datastructure. I know how to implement this structure on Java using only RAM. But I need to write data on the disk(each time when I write, modify or delete)

How can I implement this structure?

Comment: You may be able to figure out the answer if you sift through the code for any of the open source databases like SQLite, CouchDB, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this is helpful: [How does the file system store a b-tree?](http://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=22600)

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using a library. Writting BTree may look simple on paper, but with a few millions items and rebalancing it gets harder.

There is an BTree/HTree which stores its nodes on disk. It implements Map and Set interface. 
http://code.google.com/p/jdbm2/

New version of this library is under development at github:
https://github.com/jankotek/JDBM3